# ¿Cómo mostrar la venta más alta y el nombre del cliente?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen día. Tengo dos tablas en MySQL , una llamada Clientes con los campos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la otra tabla se llama ventas con los campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo es mostrar la venta mas alta y el nombre del cliente

Lo intente con esta sentencia

```
SELECT max(Costo_venta) AS 'Venta Máxima', Nombre_cliente
FROM ventas
INNER JOIN clientes ON  clientes.Id_Cliente = ventas.Cliente_IdCliente
GROUP BY clientes.Nombre_cliente;
```

Pero me devuelve esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero cual es el problema=

Answer (score 0):

El resultado de tu consulta es el correcto pero si lo que necesitas es solo un único registro lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT max(Costo_venta) AS venta_mayor, Nombre_cliente
FROM ventas
INNER JOIN clientes ON  clientes.Id_Cliente = ventas.Cliente_IdCliente
GROUP BY clientes.Nombre_cliente ORDER BY venta_mayor DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Lo que se hace en la consulta es ordenar el resultado descendente y extraer solo el primer registro, que será el mas alto.

Answer (score 0):

Tu consulta de da la venta mas alta por cliente. Pero quieres la venta mas alta de todos y mostrar el cliente de esa venta.

Son dos pasos: Encontrar el costo de la venta mas alta. Consultar el cliente de esa venta (o esas ventas si hay mas de una venta con el mismo costo).

```
SELECT *
FROM ventas v
INNER JOIN clientes c ON c.id_cliente = v.cliente_idcliente
WHERE v.costo_venta = (SELECT MAX(costo_venta) FROM ventas);
```

Esto es un método. Hay otras maneras de hacer lo mismo. Por ejemplo con `NOT EXISTS (una venta con un costo mas alto)` o con `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY costo_venta)`.

Answer (score -1):

solo debes ordenar tus datos por la columna venta máxima.

Agrega esto a tu consulta justo despues del group by

order by max(Costo_venta) desc